# Fill the field immediately after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, formik

I have search page in my NextJS application. URL example - `/search?q=Naaarutoo`. And for example after reloading I just want to set "Naaarutoo" as the input value (*I know how to set query param to input value*) **IMMEDIATELY**.

If we look closer we will see that field didn't fulfilled:

[image]

I think this is because the server side returns simple HTML to client and only after that starts client side execution.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Formik, Form, Field} from 'formik'

const Search = ({router: {query}}) => (
  <Formik enableReinitialize onSubmit={() => {

  }} initialValues={{q: query.q || ''}} render={() => (
    <Form>
      <Field name='q' type="search" placeholder="Find something"/>
    </Form>
  )}/>
)

export default withPageRouter(Search)
```

**Last update**:

I don't know why but it works (I don't remember what I did ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) ), ok, thanks all for your help.

Comment: Use the `enableReinitialize` prop on `Formik`. By default, Formik will not re-render if `initialValues` changes. This is a bit of a hack, but it works.

Comment: @DanPantry, I have `enableReinitialize` in my code. Forgot to add here, ooups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need getInitialProps to use query

```
import React from 'react'
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik'

const Search = ({ query }) => (
    <Formik onSubmit={() => { }} initialValues={{ q: query.q || '' }} render={() => (
        <Form>
            <Field name='q' type="search" placeholder="Find something" />
        </Form>
    )} />
)

Search.getInitialProps = ({ query }) => {
    return { query }
}

export default Search
```

I checked it and it works fine for me.

Comment: May be make a quick stackblitz? We can help better.

Comment: One second, I have new idea